# radio buttons value if statement

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, radio-button, radio-group

I have several groups of radio buttons that I want to use in an IF statement (or if you have a better solution)

Users will come to the site, select the buttons, then select submit. After submitting, I want the user to see instantly if they should "`refer patient`" or "`don't refer patient`".
I am not sure of a couple of things:

1. How do I make the "submit" button cause the input to be calculated (meaning, the user gets the instant response)
2. Since there are several combinations of inputs that can create a "refer" or "don't refer" response, can I add multiple conditions to the IF statement? Also, how can I include radio buttons in the statement - do I just use the "value" of the button. I only learned the very basic method of using numbers..

Below is my code so far. I tried to start the IF statement with values. Not sure if doing it right.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Indications for Mohs</title>
<?php
    $Patient_status='unchecked';
    $Primary_status='unchecked';
    $Type_status='unchecked';
    $BCCT_status='unchecked';
    $SCCT_status='unchecked';
    $Size_status='unchecked';
    $Area_status='unchecked';
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $selected_radio=$_POST['REFER'];
        if (selected_radio == "Healthy" && "Primary" && "BCC" && "Aggressive" && "<0.6" && "H" or "Immunocompromised" && "Primary" && "BCC" && "Aggressive" && "<0.6" && "H")

?>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Indications" action="" method="POST">
<p><h2><strong><u>Indications for Mohs Surgery</u></strong></h2> 
</p>
<strong>Patient </strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Patient" value="Healthy">Healthy<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Patient" value="Immunocompromised">Immunocompromised<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Patient" value="Genetic">Genetic Syndrome<br>
    <hr>
<strong>Primary vs Recurrent</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Primary" value="Primary">Primary<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Primary" value="Recurrent">Recurrent<br>
      <hr>
<strong>Type</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="BCC">BCC<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="SCC">SCC<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="LM">LM or MIS<br>
      <hr>
<strong>BCC subtype</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="BCCT" value="Aggressive">Aggressive<br>
      <input type="radio" name="BCCT" value="Nodular">Nodular<br>
      <input type="radio" name="BCCT" value="Superficial">Superficial<br>
      <hr>
<strong>SCC subtype</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="Aggressive">Aggressive<br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="Nonaggressive">Nonaggressive<br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="Verrucous">Verrucous<br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="KA">KA - type SCC<br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="Bowen">In situ SCC/Bowen<br>
      <input type="radio" name="SCCT" value="AK">AK<br>
      <hr>
<strong>Size (cm)</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Size" value="0.5"><0.6<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Size" value="0.6-1">0.6-1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Size" value="1.1-2">1.1-2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Size" value="2">>2<br>
      <hr>
<strong>Area</strong>
<div alighn="center"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Area" value="H">H<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Area" value="M">M<br>
      <input type="radio" name="Area" value="L">L<br>
      <hr>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
<p><strong><u>Definitions</u>:</strong><br>
  Nonaggressive SCC: &lt;2mm depth without other defining features, Clark level ≤III<br>
  Area H: 'Mask Areas' of face (central face, eyelids, eyebrows, nose, lips [cutaneous/mucosal/vermillion], chin, ear, and periauricular skin/sulci, temple), genitalia (including perineal and perianal), hands, feet, nail units, ankles, nipples/areola<br>
  Area M: Cheeks, forehead, scalp, neck, jawline, pretibial surface<br>
  Area L: Trunk and extremities (excluding pretibial surface, hands, feet, nail units and ankles)</p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP has `in_array()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the submit display a response instantly you should use JavaScript as this does not require a form submission/call to a server. You can use the onsubmit event.

Regarding checking for if a radio button is checked, use the .checked property of an element:

```
document.getElementById('elem').checked //true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is wrong with that code.

Let's start...

You don't have a REFER element in your form, so `$_POST['REFER']` is never set. To access radio button values, you need to access with their relevant name as the index key to the `$_POST[]` array. E.g. `$_POST['Patient'], $_POST['Primary']` ...etc. Those will give you the value of the radio button selected within that group.

Secondly, your conditional statements are wrong in the `if statement`. To compare conditional statements, you have to specifically compare the variable with different values every time. You'd have to say

```
if ($selected_radio == "Healthy" && $selected_radio == "Patient") {
    // code goes here
}
```

And also, to check which radio button was selected, you need to access `$_POST['<Radio_group_name>']` and this will give you the value of the radio button selected for that group. e.g.

```
$_POST['Patient']
```

would give `Healthy` if user selected that one for the group.